# CakePHP, Can't seem to get a theme to apply

Tags: cakephp, themes

I have a fresh install of CakePHP 1.3.4 Stable. I created a very simple application and i am trying to get it to use the theme directory view and layout instead of the default.

**\app\controllers\tests_controller.php**

```
<?php
class TestsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Tests';
    var $uses = array();
    var $theme = 'rgr';


    function index() {
        $this->theme = 'rgr';
        $this->layout = 'default';

        echo "Controler = TestsController::index() ";
    }
}
```

**\app\views\layouts\default.ctp**

```
<?php echo $html->docType(); ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Layout = No theme 
        <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>  
    </body>
</html>
```

**\app\views\tests\index.ctp**

```
<div class="test index">
    test index, no theme
</div>
```

**\app\views\themed\rgr\layouts\default.ctp**

```
<?php echo $html->docType(); ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
         Layout = RGR
        <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>  
    </body>
</html>
```

**\app\views\themed\rgr\tests\index.ctp**

```
<div class="test index">
    View=test index, RGR theme
</div>
```

I have read the [themes section of the 1.3 manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1093/Themes), and a few o[ther posts](http://blog.room34.com/archives/4480) on the subject But I have yet to figure it out. Currently the out put is

**Output**

```
Controler = TestsController::index() Layout = No theme
test index, no theme, v2
```

I expected to see

```
Controler = TestsController::index() Layout = RGR
View=test index, RGR theme
```

I'm thinking its a simple mistake as there does not seem to be anyone else with the same problem. I have turned off catching in the core.php.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `var $view = 'Theme'` in the controller.That's necessary.